# Link chart and Google Map

Tags: google-maps, google-visualization

I have a map on my page which display a kml file, I have also a chart showing the elevation profile of the kml, what I want to do is when I pass on the chart it shows on the map the point correponding like you can do in Google Earth when uploading a kml and show the profile.

I do not know how to do this, any help will be appreciated !

Thanks !

Comment: can you post a link to your page?

Comment: Hi, I do not have a public link yet it is still in dev locally (personal project), more details, I am uploading a GX file, parse it to create a KML and say a table to generate a chart for the elevation profile or speed, KML file is then show onto a google map and the chart is displayed below, what I want to achieve is when you pass over the chart it display some information (ie elevation value plus distance value from beginning)

Comment: this part is ok, but I want to dynamically show a marker corresponding to the coordinates (table for chart contains distance (X), elevation (Y), lat and long) onto the map so you can see what elevation/speed correspond to the trail.